# Counting rows in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm designing a function in VBA of the form myFunction(x,y,z) where z is a table, and x can take the values of the column headings. As part of the function I need to find the number of rows in z.

I'm having problems with this, as everywhere I look suggests using `length = z.Rows.Count`, but when I try and output this value (as in, set `myFunction = length`), it produces a VALUE error. However, when I output `myFunction = a` which doesn't directly use `length` (it will eventually form part of an IF statement once I get it working), the function works fine. My code is below:

```
Public Function myFunction(x As String, y As Double, z As Range) As Double

    Dim upper_threshold As Double
    Dim lower_threshold As Double
    Dim a As Double

    Dim rates As Variant

    Dim u As Byte
    Dim l As Byte
    Dim r As Byte

    Dim length As Byte


    a = 0

    u = 2
    l = 1

    rates = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(z, 1, 0)
    r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(x, rates, 0)

    length = z.rows.Count

    upper_threshold = z(u, 1)

    Do While y > upper_threshold

        u = u + 1
        l = l + 1

        upper_threshold = z(u, 1)
        lower_threshold = z(l, 1)

        If y < upper_threshold Then
            a = a + z(l, r) * (y - lower_threshold)
        Else
            a = a + z(l, r) * (upper_threshold - lower_threshold)
        End If

    Loop

myFunction = a

End Function
```

To test it out I also created another function:

```
Public Function myRows(myTable As Range) As Double

    myRows = myTable.rows.Count

End Function
```

This one works fine on its own, but when I try to use it within the other function, I still get a VALUE error. I've tried declaring length as every type I can think of and it doesn't seem to help.

Can anyone see what's going on?

EDIT: I'm obviously not making myself very clear. The function without the two lines referring to length works as I intended. However, I need to add a bit of code to increase its functionality and this involves calculating the number of rows in the table z. When I add the two lines shown here into the function it continues to work, since it doesn't affect the output. However, if I then set the output to show length, i.e. change the penultimate line to `myFunction = length` it gives me a VALUE error. This leaves me with two options as far as I can see: either something else in the program is impacting on these two lines (some clashes of syntax or something), or I'm making a mistake in just assuming I can output `length` like that.

Comment: are you aware that [**`Byte`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164754(v=office.10).aspx) holds values only between 0 and 255? You could be getting an overflow error if the number of rows in `z` is greater than 255. If you didn't know that then try to declare `length` as `Long` instead.

Comment: It will only ever be up to about 10, so byte is fine. As I said, I've also tried declaring it as various other types as well. Double, variant, long...

Comment: have you tried passing the `z` `byRef`?

Comment: What does that do? (Sorry, I'm not very familiar with VBA!) What I don't really understand is that the second function is essentially an extremely cut down version of the first, and it works fine. So I don't get why it's not working in the upper version. Although the rest of the function works on its own, there must be something within it that "interrupts" the counting of the rows in some way.

Comment: I am sorry but you do not get it :) the `.Rows.Count` property belong to a `Range object`. It does return the last row used within the range. Both `length = z.Rows.Count` and `myRows = myTable.Rows.Count` function identically. Your problem is somewhere else and I think Doug has given you the answer

Comment: If I delete the two lines which mention length the function works absolutely as intended. So it can't be that that's wrong.

Comment: If it works absolutely as intended without those lines, why not just eliminate them? I still encourage you to try to clarify this question, with the simplest possible sample of what doesn't work. Also in your question, you refer in one place to using `Set` when calling the function, and in another you don't. It would also help if your variable names were all descriptive. Finally, I'd declare anything having to do with `Rows.Count` as a `Long`, and actually do it in your example, so we don't have to guess at what you are "really" doing.

Comment: Please see my edit at the bottom of the original post. I can't be any clearer than that. If you still don't understand, then don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with:

```
rates = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(z, 1, 0)
```

`Index` only accepts a single row or column, otherwise you get a `VALUE` error.

Comment: No, that's not the problem, since I know it was working before. The problem is definitely with just the counting  of rows. As you can see, the length isn't used directly in the calculation as I've shown it. Once I've got it working, it will just become a condition in an if loop. The output of the function is correct, but when I try to output length I get the value error.

Comment: +1 for digging that deep. If someone says `this` doesnt work it probably means that `something else` actually doesnt

Comment: When asking questions, I suggest paring your example to the simplest one that demonstrates the issue. That way people aren't distracted by your other coding errors :).

Comment: Fair enough, except that I don't understand how that line can be wrong since it works absolutely fine, when I remove the two lines related to length. EDIT: I'm not sure I can reduce the example because if the function I gave below works then it must be something somewhere else?